# Mapper not initialized in asp.net web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

This code is for Employee Controller class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using Xebia.EmployeeDB.DAL;
using AutoMapper;

namespace Xebia.EmployeeDB.API.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/Employee")]
    public class EmployeeController : ApiController
    {

        [Route("")]
        public IEnumerable<Employee> Get()
        {
            using (EmployeeDataEntities entity = new EmployeeDataEntities())
            {
                return Mapper.Map<List<Employee>>(entity);
                //var mapper = cfg.CreateMapper();
            }
        }
}
```

This is the AutomapperConfig class File.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AutoMapper;
using Xebia.EmployeeDB.DTO;

namespace Xebia.EmployeeDB.DAL
{
    public class AutomapperConfig
    {
        //public AutomapperConfig()
        //{
        public static void Initialze()
        {
            //Mapper.Initialize(cfg => 
//Employee is the class under Data access layer class library and EmployeeDto is the class inside DTO class library.
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDto>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.SerialNumber, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SerialNumber))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.MiddleName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MiddleName))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.EmailID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EmailID))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.JoiningDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.JoiningDate))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AnnualCTC, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AnnualCTC))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DesignationID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DesignationID))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CurrencyID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CurrencyID))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.LocationID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LocationID))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ProjectID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProjectID))
    ;
            });

            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<EmployeeDto, Employee>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.SerialNumber, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.SerialNumber))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.MiddleName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.MiddleName))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.EmailID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EmailID))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.JoiningDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.JoiningDate))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.AnnualCTC, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AnnualCTC))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.DesignationID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.DesignationID))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CurrencyID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CurrencyID))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.LocationID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LocationID))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ProjectID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ProjectID))
    ;
            });
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Xebia.EmployeeDB.DAL;

namespace Xebia.EmployeeDB.API
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            AutomapperConfig.Initialze();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        }
    }
```

Please suggest what need to be done. How to Initialize the mapper as the exception is coming when the execution reaches the return statement inside Get method in Employee Controller class. 
In the solution I made three projects : 1 . For API  2. For DAL   3.For DTO
My DAL includes the automapperconfig class file and Dto includes the classes EmployeeDTo etc. 
My API includes the Employeecontroller and get method and it shows error exception when the execution reaches to return statement inside Get method.

I have Added Global.asax file in here where i called Automapperconfig.Initialize method but it showed the error on execution.
Error : Already called.

Comment: What is EmployeeDataEntities over here?

Comment: EmployeeDataEntities is the connection string name in App.config file that i got when i implemented ADo.Net entity Model.@JaliyaUdagedara

Comment: where you call AutomapperConfig.Initialze()

Comment: I added it in Global.asax but after adding I got the error that it has already been initialzed.@levent

Comment: Here technically, you are missing a mapping configuration which says, when I pass a `EmployeeDataEntities`, map it to a entity of type `Employee (CreateMap<EmployeeDataEntities, Employee>())`. But I am not sure, why you have done, `using (EmployeeDataEntities entity = new EmployeeDataEntities())`

Comment: How to map it to a entity of type Employee